# how to insert multiple rows in table in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert more upto 50 rows by single query using this code, how can be it possible either by using array or using loop

Thanks in Advance

```
<?php


require 'conn/Session.php';

require 'conn/MySQL.php';

require_once("includes/generalFunction.php");

require_once("classes/class.SiteManager.php");

$dbcon =  new MySQL();

$siteObj =  new SiteManager();

require 'conn/checkSession.php';

if($_POST['submit']) 
{


            $content=array("student_id"=>$_POST['student_id'],"parent_id"=>$_POST['parent_id'],"student_name"=>$_POST['student_name'],"s_status"=>$_POST['s_status'],"class"=>$_POST['class'],"section"=>$_POST['section']);

            $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content);
            $mess="Record created successfully.";
            $url="all_attandence.php?mess=".base64_encode($mess);
            redirectPage($url);

}
?>
```

Comment: `$dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content); $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content1); $dbcon->insert_query("tbl_attandence",$content2);`

Comment: thanks that is working now but got one more issue at status i am using 3 chekbox when i enter different values per check box the value is the same as i entered i last check box...how to get different value for every check box

Comment: You've got some kind of wrapper involved here, so you'll have to figure out if that can be optimized more. Typically a single prepared statement can be used multiple times with different data.